# Android equivalent to CSS background-size: cover

Tags: android, css, image

I was wondering if there is an equivelant function in Android to CSS's background-size: cover?

I am making a small application for college and want too have an image in my splash screen. I have a Nexus 9 which has a resolution of 2048 x 1536 and I am finding it difficult to find an image with this resolution. So I looked into scale-type etc but all of these solutions seem to change the proportions of the image. Which in turn makes it stretched and looks horrible.

I currently have this inside a relative layout:

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/gts"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
```

But for whatever reason this is changing the proportion of the image. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

U must make android_width as wrap content and android_height as wrap content also u must set scaleType=fitcenter

'android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content
android:scaleType="fitCenter"'